# Microsoft Edge calling onload named function on page loading

Tags: javascript, onload, microsoft-edge

A simple html like this one above, opened on Edge ,would show the alert.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        var onload = function() {
            alert('I\'ve been called');
        };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body> my body </body>
</html>
```

More, if you add `window.addEventListener('load', onload, false);` to your code, the function get called **twice**..

I have a web app and my onload functions are called twice on everypage...

1. Would there be a way to disable this *feature*, server side so the function would only be called once without any need to refactor all my code?
2. Is this a known bug or a behavior we will need to take into account from now on?

Comment: I guess `var onload` actually sets `window.onload`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're assigning a function to `window.onload` AND you're installing an event listener to the window load event.  You are hooking up two event listeners to the same function so it is getting called twice.

Remember, global variables are all properties of the `window` object too so when you do:

```
var onload = function() {...}
```

in the global namespace, that is identical to doing:

```
window.onload = function() {...}
```

Which is configuring an event handler.

If you don't want this problem, then change the name of your `onload` function to something that doesn't conflict with `window.onload` or use an anonymous function (this is a great example of why you should use an anonymous event handler whenever possible and avoid using the global namespace whenever possible).

---

I would suggest either this:

```
// anonymous function
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    alert('I\'ve been called');
}, false);
```

or this:

```
// use IIFE function to insulate from global namespace
(function() {
    var onload = function() {
        alert('I\'ve been called');
    };
    window.addEventListener('load', onload, false);
})();
```

Comment: I agree with that. Do you know however why then, the problem would not occur on other browsers, even IE 11, 10 etc?

Comment: @oldergod - I do not know why it would not occur in those browsers (it seems to me that it would).  The code is going to cause trouble so best just to avoid the trouble.  Great reasons to avoid global functions or variables whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing related to microsoft edge. It's just ES6 that is implemented into edge, and not yet in other browsers. It's not a bug, it's a feature.

So, your code will break in chrome, firefox too within few weeks.
https://thechamplord.wordpress.com/2014/07/04/using-javascript-window-onload-event-properly/  
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197055%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Also, why would you give a function with such a name?

Comment: I could not find any source that would link this behavior to ES6. Do you have any?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to disable this. Avoid polluting the global namespace like that and simply wrap your function in an IIFE. It will help with garbage collection as well for other scenarios.

```
(function(){
    var onload = function() {
        alert('I\'ve been called');
    };
    window.addEventListener('load', onload, false);
})()
```